# How can I call an Angular function on each page view?

Tags: angularjs

Right now I am using `angular.element(document).ready(init());` but it calls `init();` on every page refresh and not when browsing back and forth to the page. How could I call this function on every page view ?

I've tried also `onload` and `ng-init` and they don't work - the function doesn't get called.

Comment: Do your pages have different controllers? You could run the function everytime a controller is loaded?

Comment: @MHakvoort yes they have different controllers. And yes.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @CallumLinington I am calling a callback to load some table data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

> [**$routeChangeSuccess**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) Broadcasted after a route change has happened successfully. The resolve dependencies are now available in the
>   current.locals property.
>
> ngView listens for the directive to instantiate the controller and
>   render the view.

This is what I do and it works for me:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
  // do something
});
```

Unless you're using ui-router. Then it's:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  // do something
});
```

More info is found in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: TBH it works but it seems the plugin I am using has some kind of bug and `ngular.element(document).ready(init());` forces its load. Is there any other way to force load of this function on every page view ?